# Using VBA, How to Create CheckBox in a UserForm passing the RecordSet Fields

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, checkbox, userform

I have Command Button which is required to show a User Form Dynamically as Below, with the Column Headers fetched from a Record Set as a Check Box Option.

[image: Table Range]

[image: User Form]

The Code that I Have for Initialize is as below

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set xl1 = Excel.Application
    Dim xlXML As Object
    Dim adoRecordset As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim recordCount1 As Long
    Dim Fieldcount1 As Long
    xl1.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate
    Set rng = xl1.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1:I15")
    Set adoRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set xlXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xlXML.LoadXML rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)
    adoRecordset.Open xlXML
    adoRecordset.MoveFirst
    Fieldcount1 = adoRecordset.Fields.Count
    Dim i As Long
    Dim chkBox As CheckBox
    For i = 1 To Fieldcount1
        Set chkBox = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i)
        chkBox.Caption = adoRecordset.Fields(i - 1)
        chkBox.Value = False
        chkBox.Top = (chkBox.Height + Spacing) * (i - 1)
    Next i

End Sub
```

I am getting "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" error

Could you please help me on this.

I am relatively a beginner in Scripting

Comment: What line of code is giving you the run-time error?

Comment: @OpiesDad.The code fails at Set chkBox = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i) –  Vikram 7 mins ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the variable declaration.  You need:

```
Dim chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox
```